# Lining/Proportional numbers in footnote marks

Tags: fonts, footnotes, fontspec, overleaf

I am currently working on a Book and I need to use Lining, Proportional numbers for the footnotes superscript, not the footnote itself. I am using fontspec and the following fonts:

```
\setmainfont[BoldFont=DGMetaSerifScience-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont=DGMetaSerifScience-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=DGMetaSerifScience-BoldItalic.otf
]{DGMetaSerifScience-Regular.otf}

\setsansfont[BoldFont=DGMetaScience-Bold.otf,
ItalicFont=DGMetaScience-Italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=DGMetaScience-BoldItalic.otf
]{DGMetaScience-Regular.otf}
```

Adding `\AtBeginDocument{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining, Proportional}}}` to the preamble makes no difference. Also, adding the following line within the setting of the fonts does nothing: Numbers={Lining, Proportional}.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the font family not have real superiors? If it does, the `realscripts` package would give the best output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your font, but some fonts default to Lining and lack the explicit "lnum" feature. Have you tried just specifying "Proportional" and letting it default to Lining?